# HTTP parsing library for linux C++

Tags: c++, linux, http

can anyone suggest a good HTTP parsing library for linux?

Comment: http or html? probably html... right?

Comment: Obviously a very wrong question if you tagged libcurl as an answer as libcurl does not offer any HTTP parsing at all (it does it internally).  You asked for a HTTP transport library.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/)?

It supports most web-based protocols, widely used, and stable. Available on most Linux distributions and should be around for Windows too. It supports both a simplified interface for quick-and-dirty implementations as well as an advanced interface for a robust implementation.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a C++ wrapper for curl, you might like curl++. Do look it up.